# Getting several parameters from dynamic routing in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

Assume this folder structure:

```
- src
    - pages
        - jobs
            - [id].js
```

And for the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/jobs/123
```

You can access `123` inside `[id].js` page as well. Now I need to get one more parameter there named `title`. Something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/jobs/123/jobtitle
```

How can I do that? I'm looking for something like this `[id,title].js`, but I don't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- pages 
   - jobs
      - [id]
         - [jobtitle].js
```

Now you can get `id` and `title` from `http://localhost:3000/jobs/123/jobtitle`.

[There is a way about catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes)

```
- pages
   - jobs
      [[...slug]].js
```

The query objects are as follows:
`http://localhost:3000/jobs` -> {}
`http://localhost:3000/jobs/id` -> [id]
`http://localhost:3000/jobs/id/jobtitle` -> [id, jobtitle]

Comment: Yeah right .. just isn't there abit dirty? making nested `[id]` directory just for getting a parameter?

Comment: @MartinAJ I was remember something about `catch all routes`, but I didn't write it because I wasn't sure. I did a little research, yes it still exists.

Comment: Thanks, tested, but it throws 404 not found, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBdOR.png

Comment: @MartinAJ Have you tried deleting the`index.js` file in the `jobs` ?

Comment: Oh, very good, done